# Scala parser combinators converting list of characters to strings

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have been trying to get my head around Scala's parser combinators. It seems that they are pretty powerful but the only tutorial examples I seem to find are with mathematical expressions and very little proper real-world parsing examples with DSLs that need to be parsed and mapped to different entities etc.

For the sake of this example, lets say I have this BNF where I have this entity named Model, which is made up of a string like this: `[model [name <name> ]]`. This is a simplistic example of a much larger BNF I have and there are more entities in reality.

So I defined my own class `Model` which takes the `name` as the constructor and then defined my own `ModelParser` object which extends `JavaTokenParsers`. I then defined the following parsers, following the BNF (I know some may have a simpler regex matcher but I preferred to follow the BNF exactly for other reasons).

```
def model : Parser[Model] = "[model" ~> "[name" ~> name <~ "]]" ^^ ( Model(_) )
def name : Parser[String] = (letter ~ (anyChar*)) ^^ {case text => text.toString())
def anyChar = letter | digit | "_".r | "-".r
def letter = """[a-zA-Z]""".r
def digit = """\d""".r
```

The `toString` of `Model` looks like this:

```
override def toString : String = "[model " + name + "]"
```

When I try to run it with a string like `[model [name helloWorld]]` I get this 
`[model [h~List(e, l, l, o, W, o, r, l, d)]]` instead of what I am expecting `[model helloWorld]`

How do I get those individual characters to join back in the string they were originally in?

I am also confused with the individual parsers and the use of `.r`. Sometimes I saw examples where they had just the following as a parser (to parse "hello"):

```
def hello = "hello"
```

Isn't that just a String? How on Earth did it suddenly become a parser that can be combined with other parsers? And what is the `.r` actually doing? I have read at least 3 tutorials but still totally lost what is actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `anyChar*` parses a `List[String]` (where in this case each string is a single character), and the result of calling `toString` on a list of strings is `"List(...)"`, not the string you'd get by concatenating the contents. In addition, the `case text =>` pattern is matching on the entire `letter ~ (anyChar*)`, not just the `anyChar*` part.

It's possible to address both of these issues pretty straightforwardly:

```
case class Model(name: String) {
  override def toString : String = "[model " + name + "]"
}

import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object ModelParser extends RegexParsers {
  def model: Parser[Model] = "[model" ~> "[name" ~> name <~ "]]" ^^ (Model(_))

  def name: Parser[String] = letter ~ (anyChar*) ^^ {
    case first ~ rest => (first :: rest).mkString
  }

  def anyChar = letter | digit | "_".r | "-".r
  def letter = """[a-zA-Z]""".r
  def digit = """\d""".r
}
```

We just append the first character string to the list of the rest, and then call `mkString` on the entire list, which will concatenate the contents. This works as expected:

```
scala> ModelParser.parseAll(ModelParser.model, "[model [name helloWorld]]")
res0: ModelParser.ParseResult[Model] = [1.26] parsed: [model helloWorld]
```

As you note, it would be possible (and possibly clearer and more performant) to let the regular expressions do more of the work:

```
object ModelParser extends RegexParsers {
  def model: Parser[Model] = "[model" ~> "[name" ~> name <~ "]]" ^^ (Model(_))

  def name: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z\d_-]+""".r
}
```

This example also illustrates the way that the parsing combinator library uses implicit conversions to cut down on some of the verbosity of writing parsers. As you say, `def hello = "hello"` defines a string, and `"[a-zA-Z]+".r` defines a [`Regex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) (via [the `r` method on `StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps)), but either can be used as a parser because [`RegexParsers`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers) defines implicit conversions from `String` (this one's named `literal`) and `Regex` (`regex`) to `Parser[String]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications, especially the `.r` confusion and the implicit conversion between a String literal to `Parser[String]`. The `name` parser is working fine now!

Comment: @Travis I noticed that for some reason, even `[model [name hello World]]` is being accepted and reproduced after parsing as `helloWorld` just the same. How do I force it to not accept the name part if it has a whitespace? The ~ seems to allow it just fine. I don't want to disable it completely for the parser because it is quite useful.